# find: missing argument to -exec with ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, exec

Trying to remove directories from server:

```
ssh myname@servera ssh othername@serverb find /var/lib/jenkins/some/path/to/check -name 2.2.4* -type d -exec rm -r {} ;
```

I tried with `\;` and `\;;` and `;` and `"{}"` and `-exec sh -c 'rm -r "{}"' \;`

All get's the error `find: missing argument to "-exec'"`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly running commands with ssh is often hard to impossible when you want to use special characters. This is because ssh remotely calls `sh -c "<<COMMAND HERE>>"`. This causes the characters to be quoted / unquoted twice and sometimes even removed.

Your best option is to create a tempfile with your command on the remote system and execute it:

```
echo 'find /var/lib/jenkins/some/path/to/check -name 2.2.4* -type d -exec rm -r {} \;' > script
scp script myname@servera:
ssh myname@servera bash script
```

In your case, you may use find's `-delete` command instead of `-exec`.

Comment: unfortunatly `-delete` only deletes empty directorys. that's why i tried `rm -r`

Answer (score 1):

@cbley is right, doing this is quite tricky. Nevertheless sometimes one wants to avoid creating an extra file. If so, you can make it this way:

```
ssh myname@servera " \"${cmd}\" "  2>&1
```

where $cmd would be your whole command defined right before:

```
cmd="find /var/lib/jenkins/some/path/to/check -name 2.2.4* -type d -exec rm -r {} ;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than nesting calls to `ssh`, use the `-J` option and send your command as a single argument, not a sequence of arguments that `ssh` has to join together.

```
ssh -J myname@servera othername@severb \
  "find /var/lib/jenkins/some/path/to/check -name '2.2.4*' -type d -exec rm -r {} \;"
```

This way, you only have to worry about your command passing through a single shell.

Comment: using OpenSSH_6.7p1, says there is no `-J` option

Comment: `-J` is a shortcut for `-o ProxyJump=...`; not sure if it's just the short cut that is new, or the option itself.

Comment: your right, [OpenSSH Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH%2FCookbook%2FProxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two) says: `In older versions -J is not available. In this case the safest and most straightforward way is to use ssh(1)'s stdio forwarding (-W) mode to "bounce" the connection through an intermediate host.` thanks chepner

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.
my final solution was not with a new script, i just temporarly saved it in an array (seemed easier for me and my bash skills):

```
dirArray=( $(ssh myname@servera ssh othername@serverb find /var/lib/jenkins/some/path/to/check -name 2.2.4* -type d) )

for i in "${dirArray[@]}"
do
  echo "deleting $i"
  ssh myname@servera ssh othername@serverb rm -r $i
done
```